# AWS - list all buckets under organization or account using the aws sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket, aws-sdk-net

Is there a way to list all the aws s3 buckets of an organization or under each of the organization accounts?
I'm using the aws .net sdk and need to get all the buckets the organization has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a simple way to do this.

You can use credentials for the master account to list all member accounts and then assume a role in each member account to list its S3 buckets. If you created the member accounts using organizations (as opposed to inviting the accounts to become members of the organization) then you can assume the preconfigured role named [OrganizationAccountAccessRole](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html).

Also, see [Running AWS CLI Commands Across All Accounts In An AWS Organization](https://alestic.com/2019/12/aws-cli-across-organization-accounts/).

Comment: How, programmatically using the sdk, do I iterate the list of accounts and get the list of buckets of every one of them?

Comment: This should be very simple. Read the SDK docs for Organizations and S3.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now I have another issue -  after assuming the role, I need to specify the Region for the S3 client before calling ListObjectsV2Async to get the buckets content in each account. Do I need to know the region of each bucket or just use the USEast1 region?

Comment: You should be able to invoke `ListObjects*` without explicitly providing a region. Did you try this and did it fail?

Comment: I'm working with the c# sdk. I'm creating new AmazonS3Client and give it the STS temporary credentials. If I'm not supplying also a region to the client and call ListObjects(), I get exception - "No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured"

Comment: Ok, I was assuming that credentials would be supplied implicitly through a role or credentials file. It should be say to test this. Supply us-east-1 and then list both a bucket in us-east-1 and a bucket in a different region.